# Next.js The page cannot be routed

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, next.js, styled-components

**Development environment**
next.js
Typescript
Styled-components

**What I did in building next.js environment**
yarn create next-app
yarn add --dev typescript @types/react @types/node
yarn add styled-components
yarn add -D @types/styled-components

I ran the four above

**I don't understand**

Executed the above command and built the environment for next.js.

I made user.tsx under the pages directory and accessed pages/users, but I got a 404 Not Found error.
Why?

> packege.json

```
{
  "name": "next-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "9.4.4",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^14.0.18",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.41",
    "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.0",
    "typescript": "^3.9.6"
  }
}
```

> 

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Sidebar from "../components/atoms/SideBar";
import UserList from "../components/atoms/UserList";

const UsersStyle = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
`;

export const User: FC = () => {
  return (
    <UsersStyle>
      <Sidebar />
      <UserList />
    </UsersStyle>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the code to a default export.

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import Sidebar from "../components/atoms/SideBar";
import UserList from "../components/atoms/UserList";

const UsersStyle = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
`;

const User: FC = () => {
  return (
    <UsersStyle>
      <Sidebar />
      <UserList />
    </UsersStyle>
  );
};

export default User;
```